# Hexadecimal to NVARCHAR from DB2 DDBB

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, hex

I'm using SSMS to query DB2 database table.

Some fields are in hexadecimal format, for example

```
0xC4C9E5C5D9E2404040404040404040
```

but if I use the DB2 viewer I know that this hexadecimal is 'DIVERS' in NVARCHAR.

How can I query the database and convert the HEX to NVARCHAR?

I've tried using:

```
CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, 0xC4C9E5C5D9E2404040404040404040, 1))
```

But the result is:

```
엙쇗쇙䁀䁀䁀䁀@
```

Comment: Column data type? (I.e. are you storing 0xC4C9E5C5D9E2404040404040404040 in a varbinary, nvarchar or varchar column?)

Comment: BTW, for DIVERS I'd expect 0x44495645525320202020.

Comment: I don't know, the field is in a linked server and i can't not query the column types

Comment: FYI SSMS is just the IDE-like application. You're (presumably) using SQL Server here to retreive the data, as you can't use SSMS to connect to a DB2 database.

Comment: I don't think that's what you think it is. If it were 'DRIVERS' as varchar stored in varbinary it would be `0x44524956455253`, or nvarchar stored as varbinary would be `0x4400520049005600450052005300`. Are you sure it's not encrypted or compressed in some way?

Comment: 0xC4C9E5C5D9E2404040404040404040 is 'DIVERS         ' encoded with EBCDIC, if your DB2 is DB2 for IBM i you have to either CAST it to VARCHAR using `CAST(x'C4C9E5C5D9E2404040404040404040' as VARCHAR(100) CCSID 37)` first in DB2 or find a way to do it in SQL Server. If you are using DB2 Z/OS i'm not sure

Comment: @nfgl yes it's DB2 for IBM

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what Db2 Platform and version you are connecting too nor the driver being used.

But I suspect that the field(s) are defined with CCSID(65535) which represents "binary" data.  Thus the DB doesn't convert it to ASCII/Unicode like it would automatically do with character data tagged with the correct CCSID.  Such as CCSID(37) for US English.

The right answer, is to get your table updated with the right CCSID for it's character columns.

The quick hack is to set a connection string option to force the DB to convert binary data to character.  For the Db2 for IBM i ODBC driver, that option is the `TRANSLATE` or `ForceTranslate`.
[image]

Note that doing this means two things

1. Any true binary data in the table will be improperly handled.
2. The DB has to guess what CCSID to translate to.

Issue 2 is likely to cause issues if your server and clients aren't both in the same country.